# How to get filtered sheet cells values with pyghseets

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

How can I get only filtered values from spreadsheet? If user have filtered some values, I don't need them.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your title, it seems that from `get filtered sheet cells values`, you want to retrieve the filtered cell values. But in your question, it seems that from `ignoring already filtered values`, you want to retrieve all values without filtering cells. So I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about it? And can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and sample output values you expect?

Comment: Values, that was filtered, I do not want to get.

Comment: And yes, you are right. I've edited the question, should be clear now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't see the vision of your goal from your replying. So I cannot still understand about your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Just think about. There is a worksheet function called `get_values()` which returns a range of values from start cell to end cell. No matter if sheet filtered or not it will always return full range of values. But I want something like `get_filtered_values()` which returns a range of values from filtered sheet. Hope it's better explanation.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to retrieve the filtered values. 1. In this case, the filter is the basic filter? There are several filters in Spreadsheet. 2. For example, when only the column "A" is shown by filtering, which do you want to retrieve only the values of column "A" or retrieve the values of except for the column "A"?

Comment: Here is an example [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-WCtDBonVfh8x_n1JO4cpxR7rLcuo0b5L-a7DK7ca8) User has filtered Col_A with "Test_1" and Col_D with "fgh" values. So i want to get 2 rows with data in A:J range (A4:J4 and A11:J11 rows)

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the sample Spreadsheet. From the sample, I thought that I could understand about your goal. So I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values from the filtered sheet.
- The filter is the basic filter.
- For example, when the values are put in the cells "A1:J25" and the values of "A4:J4" and "A11:J11" are shown by the filter, you want to retrieve the values of cells of "A4:J4" and "A11:J11".
- You want to achieve this using pygsheets.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API with pygsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, I used Query Language for this situation. At first, the access token and sheet ID are retrieved using pygsheets, and then, the values from the filtered sheet are retrieved by the Query Language. For this, I used "requests".

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
import pygsheets
import requests

service_account_file = '###'  # Please set the JSON filename including the credentials of service account.
spreadsheet_id = '###'  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'  # Please set the sheet name.

gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=service_account_file)
sh = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
wks = sh.worksheet_by_title(sheet_name)
sheet_id = wks.jsonSheet['properties']['sheetId']
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet_id + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + str(sheet_id)
res = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gc.oauth.token})
strValues = res.text
f = StringIO(strValues)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
ar = [row for row in reader]
ar.pop(0)
print(ar)
```

- In this sample script, I used the service account. If you are using OAuth2, please modify the script of authorization.
- When this script is used for your sample Spreadsheet, the values of cells of "A4:J4" and "A11:J11" can be retrieved.

#### Reference:

- [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)